# How to use emacs with rtags

Tags: json, emacs, ninja

I'm trying to use rtags in Emacs because rtags is better than gtags
I tried to follow rtags site's tutorial in FreeBSD.

Now I can compile rtags and generate "compile_commands.json" for my c++ project with ninja -t commands...

When I try to navigate source with rtags in emacs... I realized that I can only navigate with .c extension but .cc extension is not worked...

I tried to change some cc files to c file for test and it works but I can't change all cc files cause it's not my own file.

Comment: If it works when you change the filenames, then it sounds like the Emacs side is working fine. I'm guessing you just need to change the rtags command line arguments (or other config) to tell it which filename extensions to include.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these links can help you:

[EmacsWiki: BuildTags](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BuildTags)

[EmacsWiki: EmacsTags](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags)

[EmacsWiki: Tags File](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TagsFile)

Also see: `man etags`